# how to parse a Xml text in C#?

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing

I have this code in Hml

and a i need to print this in a column: 
        html
        body
        font
        color=blue
        size=3
        input
        type=text 
        name=name
        maxlength=8
        br
        font
        size=2

Reading others questions here i made this:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Parse("<html><body><font color='blue' size='3'>
    Enter your name</font><input type='text' name='name' maxlength='8'/>
    <br/><font size='2'>Maximum 8 characters</font></body></html>");

    foreach (var item in doc.Descendants().Select(n => n.Name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }       
     Console.ReadKey();
```

But this only print de names(Html,body,font,input,br and font).

My question is How do i do to print the other stuff?